# Should I filter results of hierarchical query inside or outside of CTE

Tags: sql-server-2008, common-table-expression, sql-execution-plan

I have two options to filter results of hierarchical query - within CTE or in the main query. See [Original Question for reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31916661/fetch-history-of-records/31916953?noredirect=1#comment51747933_31916953).

For example here is first option:

```
WITH CurrentRequests AS (
  SELECT
    id,
    RequestID,
    OldRequestID ,
    RequestID as TopRequestID
  FROM
    Requests
  WHERE RequestID = 6
  UNION ALL SELECT
    R.id,
    R.RequestID,
    R.OldRequestID, 
    C.TopRequestID as TopRequestID
  FROM
    CurrentRequests C
    INNER JOIN Requests R
      ON R.RequestID = C.OldRequestID
)
SELECT *
FROM
 CurrentRequests;
```

[SqlFiddle A](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f0945/15)

Compared to second:

```
WITH CurrentRequests AS (
  SELECT
    id,
    RequestID,
    OldRequestID ,
    RequestID as TopRequestID
  FROM
    Requests
  UNION ALL SELECT
    R.id,
    R.RequestID,
    R.OldRequestID, 
    C.TopRequestID as TopRequestID
  FROM
    CurrentRequests C
    INNER JOIN Requests R
      ON R.RequestID = C.OldRequestID
)
SELECT *
FROM
 CurrentRequests 
WHERE TopRequestID  = 6;
```

[SqlFiddle B](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f0945/14)

The execution plans look the same.

Should I give any preference to one option, or they are the same?

Comment: I trust you that the plan looks the same, but trusting an optimized plan is inferior to "helping out" with knowledge you have. Same goes for hints... The fact that currently the optimizer manages to get the best plan shouldn't hold you from using the more obvious version (A)

Comment: Why is it more obvious? for me (B) is obvious! it is more reusable sort of, cause CTE is generic and also conditions are easier to find in the end of the query, rather than when they are spread around.

Comment: Yes I agree, what I meant was that its more obvious that the execution will apply the filter before recursion, as opposed to doing it in the end.

Comment: All examples I saw have it inside, so possibly there is a reason for that, but I personally don't see any benefits in that.

Comment: It's an opinionated issue I guess, but to reiterate my thought, I feel more confident with it inside so that I make sure the plan optimizer & execution skip all useless rows in the first iteration.